# BaseQuery.paginate() return inconsistent results

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When I manually execute this query in MySQL, the number of results I get is 28:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM position_reporting_structures prs
    INNER JOIN positions AS pos ON pos.id = prs.reports_to
    INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.id = pos.job_id
    INNER JOIN position_fulfillments AS pf ON pf.position_id = pos.id
    INNER JOIN parties ON parties.id = pf.party_id
    WHERE jobs.title LIKE '%QA/QC%' OR parties.name LIKE '%QA/QC%';
```

This is the interpreted SQLAlchemy value of the query above:

```
    query = (
          PositionReportingStructure.query 
          .join(Position,
                Position.id == PositionReportingStructure.reports_to)
          .join(Job,
                Job.id == Position.job_id)
          .join(PositionFulfillment,
                PositionFulfillment.position_id == Position.id)
          .join(Party,
                Party.id == PositionFulfillment.party_id)
          .filter(db.or_(
                Job.title.like('%QA/QC%'),
                Party.name.like('%QA/QC%')))
     )
```

I have a pagination decorator that wraps a function whose returning value is a `BaseQuery`. Inside the decorator, these are the code snippets that I've used:

```
    query = f(*args, **kwargs)

    page = 1 // just a dummy value
    per_page = 5 // just a dummy value
    paginate = query.paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page)
```

I'm expecting that it will return **more or less 6 pages and 28 items in total**, but it's not. The outcome is **1 `page`, 4 `items per page`, 4 `total items` and `no previous/next pages`** which is incorrect. For further investigation, I have tried changing the value of `page` variable to compare each one:

- `page = 1` : 1 page, 4 items, 4 total items
- `page = 2` : 6 pages, 3 items, 28 total items
- `page = 3` : 6 pages, 2 items, 28 total items
- `page = 4` : 6 pages, 3 items, 28 total items
- `page = 5` : 6 pages, 5 items, 28 total items
- `page = 6` : 6 pages, 3 items, 28 total items

As you may notice, per page items is too inconsistent. Anybody who can explain what causes this contingency? I am currently using Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.0.

Comment: Please provide the SQLAlchemy and MySQL queries that are being used in this example. Without more context, we can't find the real issue.

Comment: Thanks for informing @jonafato, already provided the query and its sqlalchemy value. Please see updated content :)

Answer (score 0):

I already knew the root cause of this problem. My query returns some duplicate rows which I think is not acceptable to SQLAlchemy so in return automatically gives the distinct ones (even without using GROUP BY or DISTINCT).

As the context of my problem stated, I passed a count of 5 items in the `per_page` parameter of the `paginate` function, at the first page, it would only return 4 items since it groups the duplicate ones, thus, satisfies the paginate function's conditional statement (the one that has an emphasis):

```
    **if page == 1 and len(items) < per_page:
        total = len(items)**
    else:
        total = self.order_by(None).count()
```